# How to return list of Stored Procedure in SQL Server and WebAPI2

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

The following code contains the created procedure.

```
USE [SAMPLE_DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllGroups] 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [dbo].[QR_Groups].[Id], [dbo].[QR_Groups].[name], [dbo].[QR_Groups].[code]
    FROM [dbo].[QR_Groups]
END
```

I can't use the stored procedure because I'm getting the error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

I don't know how to return the data from the table in WebAPI.

Here is the `Controller` code:

```
public IQueryable<QR_Group> GetAllGroups()
{
    return db.GetAllGroups();
}
```

---

EDIT:

New Error Message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult‌​' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Code-first or EDMX?  How is your stored proc declared in your EF context?

Comment: @DavidTansey I've declared the stored procedure in sql server management studio

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Stored Procedures in EF but I think what you want is this

```
public IList<QR_Group> GetAllGroups() {
    return db.GetAllGroups().ToList();
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't work because it tells, that the stored procedure returns INT but I need an array with objects. I have 3 columns ( Id=int, name=string, code=string)

Comment: A list is a form of an Array but you need to figure out what the GetAllGroups is returning.  If you setup EF correctly, there should be a model that EF is using when it calls the stored procedure.  This model is what you need a list of and what should be returned via your WebAPI

Comment: I have created the stored procedure in sql server management studio. afterwards I updated my entity data model with entity framework.. And finally defined in the controller how you can see above. And now I have this error message: `(Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<WebApi.Models.getAllGroups_Result>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WebApi.Models.QR_Group>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?))`

Comment: WebApi.Models.getAllGroups_Result is the model that EF is returning.  Its very likely this is the model  you will need to return from the controller as well.  The best way to confirm is to change up your controller for a moment, var test =  db.GetAllGroups(); return test;  Put a breakpoint on the return line and debug your project.  See exactly what the GetAllGroups() method is returning.